# rewrite other requests to index.php does not work completely

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got the following .htaccess for my apache2 webserver in e. g. "some-folder":

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Folders / files to exclude from rewrite divided by Pipe goes here:
RewriteRule (^|/)web(/|$) - [L,NC]

# turn empty requests into requests for "index.php",
# keeping the query string intact
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !favicon.ico$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

for `http://host/some-folder/index/index` it works, but for `http://host/some-folder/ajax/test` it doesn´t. It should redirect both to index.php.

What went wrong?

Edit: If I set the RewriteBase to

```
RewriteBase /~alpham8/ephp/
```

it works.

So, the folder under which the .htaccess file is located (in my case a home_dir). But how can I do the same without knowing the current directory under which the .htaccess file is located?

Comment: A side note: you write of "your apache server". That suggests that you have control over the servers main configuration. If so, why do you use `.htaccess` style files? Can't you do your rewriting in the real server configuration? `.htaccess` style files are really slowing the server down, they are error prone, hard to debug and make things more complex than required.

Comment: Is `/some-folder/ajax/test` a directory by any chance? Are you getting 404 for this URI?

Comment: yes, I am getting 404 and no, `some-folder/ajax/test` isn´t a real directory. It should rewrite to index.php that is stored in some-folder (I called  the root folder in which the .htaccess and the index.php is provided `some-folder`). And yes, it´s my local development environment, so I got full access to the webserver. But I am inside an PHP Framework, so I really need a .htaccess